# How to use two computers with two monitors each as a single computer

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, display, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a Windows 7 laptop with a second monitor connected via VGA, and a Windows 8 tablet with another monitor connected via HDMI. In total, there are 4 monitors. Two on my Windows 7 Laptop, the other two on my Windows 8 tablet. I want a program that makes 2 virtual monitors on my laptop, and shows those 2 monitors on my tablet, and the tablet's external display for free. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for you is [Microsoft Garage Mouse without Borders](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460)

> Mouse without Borders is a product that makes you the captain of your
>   computer fleet by allowing you to control up to four computers from a
>   single mouse and keyboard.